# How to delete dynamically added html code block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic-forms

I have a button which dynamically creates html content enclosed in `<fieldset>` like this.:

```
<div id="box_parent"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var content = 
'<fieldset>Some Content <input id="delete_row_box" type="button" value="Delete"></fieldset>';
$("#box_parent").append(content);
```

How can I make the dynamically created delete button only deletes the html block that it only belongs to?

I'm stuck on this function:

```
$(document).on("click", '#delete_row_box', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

I think `.remove()` should do it but I don't know how to throw the correct reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select its parent then delete the `fieldset` you add

```js
$(this).parent().remove()
```

Comment: Only remember that this will also delete the Delete button created, not just the content in the fieldset.

Answer (score 2):

### Whole Content

If you want to delete the whole content in box parent using jQuery, you should use this code:

```
$(document).on("click", '#delete_row_box', function() {
    $("#box_parent").children().remove();
});
```

### One Row

**Do not use ID for repeatable tags. It's not working in JS. Just use a suitable class name as I used in examples**

If you want a specific box appended to delete, then you should either give an id to the child during append or you should place the delete button inside the each box like a close button for each item.

**If row's container is direct parent of the button**

Find the parent to remove using this code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.delete_row_box', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

**If row's container is a grand parent of the button**

Find the row you need to remove using this code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.delete_row_box', function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
});
```

- you can replace `fieldset` with the selector that matches your parent.

Answer (score 0):

try to add an id and remove that id.
This code should work fine and it will only delete "Some content", it will not remove the delete button you created. If you need to generate multiple content you can add an index when you create the content and a for or while loop to select the content to remove (with multiple delete button). You can even use a class instead of an id to delete them all in one go.

```
var content = '<fieldset><span id="content">Some Content</span> <input 
id="delete_row_box" type="button" value="Delete"></fieldset>';
$("#box_parent").append(content);

$(document).on("click", '#delete_row_box', function() {
    $("#content").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var content = '<fieldset>Some Content <input id="delete_row_box" type="button" value="Delete"></fieldset>';
$("#box_parent").append(content);

$(document).on("click", '#delete_row_box', function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box_parent"></div>
```